# How to Create a Display Rearranging UI in Flutter for Multiple Displays like Windows OS?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, user-experience

I am working on a Flutter desktop application and I need to implement a UI that allows users to rearrange displays when they connect multiple monitors, similar to the functionality in Windows OS.

The desired UI should include the following features:

- Allow users to click and drag displays to rearrange their positions.
- Update the display layout in real-time as the user drags and drops displays.

Desired layout should look like:
[image]

I have looked into the Flutter documentation and some third-party packages, but I couldn't find a straightforward solution for this specific functionality.

Has anyone implemented a similar UI in Flutter or have any suggestions on how to approach this? Any guidance, code snippets, or recommended packages would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Like your application has multiple windows and you need to choose which one is displayed on which monitor?

Comment: I want the support for dragging in both direction vertically and horizontally like we have in any display manager in OS

Comment: See my answer about using the LayoutBuilder + GestureDetector.

Comment: It is only display the UI but i want the suggestion about how to perform all the display dragging operation both in vertical and horizontally direction.

Comment: You'll have to write some code in the spots I left comments. The "onPanStart" will give you a coordinate for where they started dragging, the "onPanUpdate" tells where they are currently dragging, & "onPanEnd" will tell you the final position of their cursor. You can use those details (plus some math) to decide where in the layout builder you want to position each window.

Comment: I added a couple more comments to help you along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much control you want over the ui you can either use something like a `LayoutBuilder` combined with a `GestureDetector`

Example:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                  double LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  double height = constraints.maxHeight;
  double width = constraints.maxWidth;

  return GestureDetector(
    onPanStart: (details) {
      print("Started dragging at: (" + details.localPosition.dx + ", " + details.localPosition.dy + ")");
      // decide which section is selected
    },
    onPanUpdate: (details) {
      print("Continued dragging at: (" + details.localPosition.dx + ", " + details.localPosition.dy + ")");
      //update the position of the child widgets based on the drag position
    },
    onPanEnd: (details) {
      print("Ended dragging at: (" + details.localPosition.dx + ", " + details.localPosition.dy + ")");
      //set the final display position
    },
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        //background
        Container(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        //You'll want to control the position of the widgets based on 
        //what widget is being dragged and where it is being dragged to.

        //box 1
        Positioned(
          top: height / 3, 
          left: width / 5,
          child: Container(width: width / 5, height: height / 3, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        //box 2
        Positioned(
          top: height / 3,
          left: width / 5 * 2,
          child: Container(width: width / 5, height: height / 3, color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        //box 3
        Positioned(
          top: height / 3,
          left: width / 5 * 3,
          child: Container(width: width / 5, height: height / 3, color: Colors.grey),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}),
```

or a `ReorderableListView`
Example:

```dart
class ReorderableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderableExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReorderableExample> createState() => _ReorderableListViewExampleState();
}

class _ReorderableListViewExampleState extends State<ReorderableExample> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color oddItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.05);
    final Color evenItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.15);

    return ReorderableListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index += 1)
          Container(
            key: Key('$index'),
            color: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: Center(
              key: Key('$index'),
              child: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
            ),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The ReorderableListView lets you drag and drop things in a list, but the layout builder gives you exact control for where to place your widgets and what size to make them.